# Getting video url uploaded to YouTube via GData framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube-api, gdata

I have a question about GData Youtube framework. I am uploadind my video successfully. But i'm asking that, is it possible to get video url immediately after dissmissing my YouTubeViewController. I want to store that link in my `NSString` variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do so by using

```
NSString *url = [[[[videoEntry mediaGroup] mediaContents] objectAtIndex:0] URLString];
NSLog(@"Upload URL = %@", url);
```

in upload Ticket callback method.

Comment: Thanks for the late but true answer. :)